# Searching for fixed numeric values in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

If I want documents where `somefield` is 12345 then I can either do `"query": { "term" : {"somefield" : {"value": 12345 }}}` or `"query":  {"match" : {"somefield": 12345 }}`. Which one is faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `term` query only if you index it as a `keyword` or one of `numeric` types and it's going to be faster than a `match`. The fastest is going to be a `filter` query. It doesn't impact document scoring.

```js
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "somefield": {
            "value": 12345
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `term` query definitely works with numeric types as well, not only keywords.